# Good string hash function

Tags: python-3.x

I am building a program (in python) that reads a large text file of words.  I already wrote code to filter all 7 characters or less words  into a list in Python3.  I’m semi new to hash tables,  going to store them into a hash table! Just need to find a good string hash function to minimize collisions.  Been searching haven’t found one I like! Just made an account on this site!
My list contains 41633 words therefor my array for hash table should be about 83266  cells at least for decent desired constant time complexity!  Again semi new to data structs and hash functions!

Comment: Typically, the default behaviour of Python's `dict` (as Python calls hash tables), and the `__hash__` function associated with `str`, is good enough. 41633 words is not even a big `dict`. Have you tried the defaults, or is this premature optimisation? ;)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html?highlight=hashlib ? if you need fewer bits (and can ensure that there are no collisions) you might truncate the values of the hash functions. and if it's not for cryptographic use anyway, you could just use `hash`.

Comment: Ok I am headed to class now but I will check into __Hash__  and pythons library for hash today when I get back.  its not for cryptographic reasons, its for a school project.  I have to code it in python and in racket, both languages I did not know a month ago. I am loving python as a language.   Thank you both for the input. Glad to see people are willing to help people on this site.  I may have a question later today on a searching algorithm.  I have been working on it, and its not perfect yet.